# Bones are not bending as intended

Tags: armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

First of all, I am pretty new to all of this but wanted to try it, so I followed a tutorial from Youtube by Sabastian Lague. Although it was posted in 2016 and pretty much was changed, I tried to adjust it. However, there seems to be a problem existing in my character and I have tried to solve it for like two days, of course, squeezing this in while doing other things, but got no luck yet. I have IK bone set up and I have a pole target. The problem is that the pole angle can be adjusted however, it will also change the angle of the foot bones. But when I make the foot bone angled right, this happens [image]

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Here is the link to the file, thank you for your time. [Character](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/8dLJ5Lm0) @moonboots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *Edit* mode, you need to bend the knees a bit so that Blender knows in what direction it is supposed to bend:

[image]

Comment: That seems to be the solution after all. Thank you for time and help anyways.